# Windows Phone notifications force device uri update

Tags: windows-phone-8, push-notification, uri, mpns

I have a question about Push Notifications. As far as I know, when the App starts, it checks if exists a push channel and, if not, it creates a new channel. Also there is an event which starts when the uri is changed. And this Uri gets expired after 30 days.

But what I would like to know is: I want to send these notifications even if the user does not have the app running (let's suppose for a long time, more than 30 days).

1. Is posible to detect the Uri changed if the App is not running?
2. Could I force somehow device uri update?

EDIT:

I have read this information:

> Each time your app starts, you should pass the URI from your push
>   channel to the cloud service that sends out the push notifications. It
>   is also recommended that you pass the device ID to your cloud service
>   so that the cloud service can track to which devices the URIs are
>   assigned. If a URI changes, then the cloud service can replace the old
>   URI for that device ID. Windows Phone does not provide a framework to
>   do this, since in most scenarios apps and cloud services already have
>   their own protocols that they use to communicate with each other.

From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202940%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

According to the text, my cloud service could send the new URI to the device, instead of updating the uri from the client? If so, do you know how could I do this?

Comment: You misunderstood the text you quoted in your edit. It says you should pass the URI from your app to the cloud service, so that the cloud service can replace the URI it has stored for that device.

Comment: So, is not possible to change the App Uri from the server.

Comment: And how will the cloud service replace the URI if it has changed if there is no way in Windows Phone 8.1 to obtain an unique device ID? How do you know that it is the same device?...